# How do I access variadic members?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

```
template<typename... Types>
struct Foo;

template<typename T , typename... Types>
struct Foo<T, Types ...> : public Foo<Types ...>
{
    Foo( T member , Types ... others ) : Foo<Types ...>( others... ), m_member( member )
    {
    }

    T   m_member;
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T>
{
    Foo( T member ) : m_member( member )
    {
    }

    T   m_member;
};

int main()
{
  Foo<char,int,bool,double> f( 'a' , 42 , true , 1.234 );
}
```

I found this code somewhere on SO and I am wondering if it's completely useless? It seems to me that all members are called `m_member` so how would I access them?

If I do `cout << f.m_member;` it will print 'a', but I see no way to access the other members.

Comment: Check your favourite `std::tuple` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current implementation each derived `Foo` class shadows its parent's `m_member`. It is up to you how to implement a logic of accessing each field (via indexing, types, other).

One possibility is to access them by an overloaded templated member function taking a type or an index (reversed for simplicity):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename... Types>
struct Foo;

template <typename T, typename... Types>
struct Foo<T, Types...> : Foo<Types...>
{
    // bring get() member functions from parent class into current scope
    using Foo<Types...>::get;

    Foo(T member, Types... others) : Foo<Types...>{others...}, m_member{member} {}

    template <typename U>
    auto get(T* = nullptr)
        -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, T>::value, T&>::type
    {
        return m_member;
    }

    template <std::size_t N>
    auto get(T* = nullptr)
        -> typename std::enable_if<N == sizeof...(Types), T&>::type
    {
        return m_member;
    }

private:
    T m_member;
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T>
{
    Foo(T member) : m_member{member} {}

    template <typename U>
    auto get(T* = nullptr)
        -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, T>::value, T&>::type
    {
        return m_member;
    }

    template <std::size_t N>
    auto get(T* = nullptr)
        -> typename std::enable_if<N == 0, T&>::type
    {
        return m_member;
    }

private:
    T m_member;
};
```

Tests:

```
Foo<char, int, bool, double> a{ 'a', 42, true, 1.234 };

assert('a' == a.get<char>());
assert(42 == a.get<int>());

assert(true == a.get<1>());
assert(42 == a.get<2>());

a.get<char>() = 'b';
assert('b' == a.get<3>());
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8aab6641b6a1ba0f)

For other implementations that provide an access to members see [`std::tuple<...>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/) with its [`std::get<N>()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/get/).

A *canonical* implementation looks as below:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename... Types>
struct Foo;

template <typename T, typename... Types>
struct Foo<T, Types...> : Foo<Types...>
{
    Foo(T member, Types... others) : Foo<Types...>{others...}, m_member{member} {}
    T m_member;
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T>
{
    Foo(T member) : m_member{member} {}
    T m_member;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
struct element;

template <typename T, typename... Types>
struct element<0, Foo<T, Types...>> 
{
    using type = T;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename... Types>
struct element<N, Foo<T, Types...>> 
{
    using type = typename element<N - 1, Foo<Types...>>::type;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename... Types>
auto get(Foo<T, Types...>& f)
    -> typename std::enable_if<N == 0, T&>::type
{
    return f.m_member;
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename... Types>
auto get(Foo<T, Types...>& f)
    -> typename std::enable_if<N != 0
                              , typename element<N, Foo<T, Types...>>::type&
                              >::type
{
    Foo<Types...>& p = f;
    return get<N - 1>(p);
}

template <typename U, typename T, typename... Types>
auto get(Foo<T, Types...>& f)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, U>::value, T&>::type
{
    return f.m_member;
}

template <typename U, typename T, typename... Types>
auto get(Foo<T, Types...>& f)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, U>::value, U&>::type
{
    Foo<Types...>& p = f;
    return get<U>(p);
}
```

Tests:

```
Foo<char, int, bool, double> a{ 'a', 42, true, 1.234 };

assert(true == get<2>(a));
assert(42 == get<int>(a));

get<char>(a) = 'b';
assert('b' == get<0>(a));
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fa0d1312b13da48)

Comment: @BЈовић: the most derived implementation (with all args) shadows its parents, so accessing by `get<int>()` will return the first argument of ctor